# Read different line in java

Tags: java

I have file.txt like

> 7 10 5
>   ADD_FLIGHT SV221 Jeddah NewYork 30 7000
>   ADD_FLIGHT SV223 Jeddah London 30 4000
>   ADD_FLIGHT SV225 Jeddah Paris 30 3500
>   ADD_FLIGHT SV227 Jeddah Cairo 30 2000
>   ADD_PASS Mohammed Ali 33 M 0555788778
>   ADD_PASS Sara Maghrabi 30 F 0555111111
>   ADD_PASS Hani Ali 20 M 0555223344
>   ADD_PASS Mohammed Hafeth 33 M 0555889876
>   ADD_PASS Ahmad Sami 44 M 0555768768
>   ADD_FLIGHT SV332 Jeddah Riyadh 20 500
>   ADD_FLIGHT SV334 Jeddah Dammam 20 600
>   ADD_FLIGHT SV367 Jeddah Dubai 25 2000
>   ADD_PASS Salwa Ali 33 F 0555765672
>   ADD_PASS Faisal Amri 20 M 0555111111
>   ADD_PASS Mona Saleem 33 F 0555222112
>   ADD_PASS Ali Ali 33 M 0555743344
>   ADD_PASS Marwa Ahmad 33 F 0555545855

I want read line 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 11,12, 13 without  ADD_FLIGHT  statement

My code

```
File fin = new File("input.txt");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream (fin);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (fis));
System.out.println(br.readLine());
```

This code read first line like :

> 7 10 5

Put I want read line 2 , 3 , 4 , 5 , 11,12, 13 without  ADD_FLIGHT  statement

Help please:(

Comment: I think you don't understand how this site works. You need to create and [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please read [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
1) Read line by line in java.
2) Check if line contains ADD_FLIGHT
3) if it contains ADD_FLIGHT, replace ADD_FLIGHT with "" and print it
```

This is the code to do this thing.

```
try{
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("textfile.txt");
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String strLine;
    while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (strLine.contains("ADD_FLIGHT")) {
            System.out.println (strLine.replace("ADD_FLIGHT",""));
        } 
    }
    in.close();
}catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I'm try this cod but strLine in if(strline.contains("ADD_FLIGHT")) error I don't know why:(

Comment: check the case: strLine/strline